# Custom ICredentialProvider and GetSerialization

Tags: c++, windows, authentication

I'm trying to implement a custom ICredentialProvider but I'm a bit stuck with a couple of things

A) The flow of calls to the provider (i.e) what order, the samples from MS don't provide this.
B) How does GetSerialization fit into the equation if you are not using one of the systems built in SSPI's (Secure Service Provider Interface).  For example I do not want to store any password on the system but I do wan't to store a value for subsequent authentication attempts (which occur online).

Any help or direction of helpful articles on this would be great. I've done a whole bunch of searching so have probably seen most of them but none really help that much tbh.

Nick.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely start by reading the technical reference and understanding it intimately. The download links can be found in this question.

[Documentation for creating a Custom Credential Provider in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228499/documentation-for-creating-a-custom-credential-provider-in-windows)

GetSerialization is the process to package the gathered credentials entered into the fields defined by the credential provider credential into a format needed by the LSA. You need to do this anytime you are in a CPUS_LOGON, CPUS_UNLOCK_WORKSTATION, or CPUS_CREDUI usage scenario and using a password as an underlying authentication mechanism. I believe in certain scenarios such as Windows Hello that this still occurs as the underlying mechanism.